# Pervasive SQL Driver

Tags: php, ubuntu, odbc, pervasive

UPDATE: should be on serverfault as suggested. New post here: https://serverfault.com/questions/451220/psql-64bit-driver-error

I am having a hard time getting PHP to connect with ODBC using a Pervasive SQL driver.

I have an Ubuntu Server 12.04 and have installed the 64bit PSQL Client drivers from here:
http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/Pages/PSQL-v11-Linux-Downloads.aspx

I have setup my ODBC.ini with the DSN to my database, and I can happily connect and then run queries:

```
isql Exchequer
```

When I use PHP, odbc_connect looks OK and gives me a resource, but odbc_exec (the point at which the driver is called) then totally fails (SEG fault):

```
[Fri Aug 10 11:05:50 2012] [notice] child pid 13770 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Here is the output from gdb

```
(gdb) run /var/www/default/scripts/stock/index.php
Starting program: /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/default/scripts/stock/index.php
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffecc89700 (LWP 14514)]
[Thread 0x7fffecc89700 (LWP 14514) exited]
Halt[Inferior 1 (process 14513) exited normally]
(gdb) bt
No stack.
```

And the PHP error.log entry

```
[Fri Aug 10 15:24:53 2012] [notice] child pid 14510 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I also added in the Trace/TraceFile but I don't seem to get any output saved to the log file.

**Update 2:**

This is the simplified script I am running:

if(!$odbc = odbc_connect("exchequer","username","password")) {
    die("Connection to Exchequer failed");
}
$rows = odbc_exec($odbc,'SELECT sl.slStockCode, sl.slQtyInStock, sl.slQtyAllocated , sl.slLocCode FROM StockLocation sl WHERE sl.slLocCode IN (\'DIG\',\'WOO\',\'MEN\')');
echo "

```
".print_r($rows,true)."
```

";

The odbc_connect works (doesn't die) but I keep seeing error 342 in my browser, and "exit signal Segmentation fault" in the apache log files.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on **serverfault**?

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a bug in one of the components you are using but my best guess it is a mismatch in your components for the size of SQLLEN/SQLULEN when they were compiled. You can enable logging in unixODBC and it may give us a hint. Edit your odbcinst.ini file and add the following to the top:

```
[ODBC]
Trace=yes
TraceFile=/tmp/unixodbc.log
```

If you don't know which odbcinst.ini file you need to edit run odbcinst -j and it will tell you. Now run your PHP script and the file above should contain the log.

Or, you could run php under the debugger (gdb) and see where it falls over. For this you'll need to find where your php executable is and run something like:

```
gdb /path/to/php
```

then type "run /path/to/my/php/script" and when it falls over type "bt" to get a back trace which will tell us where it fell over.

However, if it is a SQLLEN/SQLULEN mismatch corruption is probably going on and that can mean it seg faults somewhere totally different from where the problem is. You need to verify that PHP's ODBC module, unixODBC and your ODBC driver were all built with SQLLEN and SQLULEN the same size. I'm guessing if you installed unixODBC and PHP from Ubuntu then they will match and so the odd one out will be the Pervasive driver for which you'll need to ask them.

odbcinst -j outputs the size of SQLLEN/SQLULEN that unixODBC was built using.

You can find a lot more about this at [64-bit ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html)

Comment: Thank you for a thorough response. The output of odbcinst -j specifies the size as 8:
root@hub:/var/www/default/scripts/stock# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

Comment: I also get errors when I try and install the gdb package:
apt-get: /usr/local/psql/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/local/psql/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/local/psql/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by apt-get)
apt-get: /usr/local/psql/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
`GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)

Comment: So if the ODBC driver was built with the size at 4 bytes you'd get corruption. This is not uncommon. You should be able to check with Pervasive. But you might still want to try the trace and gdb as it could be something else.

Comment: gdb gives me: (gdb) run /var/www/default/scripts/stock/index.php
Starting program: /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/default/scripts/stock/index.php
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffecc89700 (LWP 14312)]
[Thread 0x7fffecc89700 (LWP 14312) exited]
Halt[Inferior 1 (process 14311) exited normally]

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the gdb output there as it is difficult to read in a comment. However, it looks as though it exited normally so are you sure it is doing the same as it does when it segfaults? Perhaps you'd be better extracting the data access bits into a separate PHP file and checking that seg faults first.

Comment: Done. Is there anything else I can run or test to try and identify the problem?

Comment: I didn't mean gdb runs it differently but your php code might run differently if not run in its normal environment e.g., if it was expecting some posted data. The best thing to do is just to take the database access code out of your script and get that failing in a simple php script run from the command line then fire up gdb. But really, get an ODBC trace to make sure where it is falling over in your real case.

Comment: OK, I added my test PHP code. It fails instantly on the query, so I can only assume the driver is bad. I ran the installer as they said without any errors. Just can't seem to fix this one!

Comment: Sorry but I'm at YAPC::EU. If you now have a standalone PHP script you can run from the command line and it seg faults run it again under gdb as I showed above. It might help us see where it falls over. As for the tracing I think this might indicate you are not using unixODBC.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on this question? I'd like to award the answer to you but it's not solved yet!